# how to create a rounded image border?

Tags: jquery, xhtml, css

is it possible to do rounded CSS borders once the user has uploaded the image?

I want the css to make a rounded border like the image below:

I know you can do it with CSS3 but I am using aspdotnetstorefront and it forces IE7 mode.

So any css needs to work with IE7.. :(

[image]

Comment: How about asking microsoft? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb250413

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) would save your life

```
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
background: #EEFF99;
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a magically tool. What do you actually call this sort of tool?

Comment: the behavior url is relative to **html**, not **css**.

Comment: i should be pointing to the file? or simply /PIE.htc is enough?

Comment: i added the URL and placed the file in the root of the site and it worked. thanks buddy

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) or [CurvyCorners](http://www.curvycorners.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop can help you.

You cannot do any CSS3+ effects with IE7-

Comment: @SLaks -- yes true, you can use some javascript fix -- but that is **not** pure css.